# Connect to a domain without internet

Tags: networking

I have a computer connected to my workplace AD domain where through this connection it has access to the internet and also can connect to a server located on that domain e.g 150.130.xxx.xxx. I wonder how I can keep the connection to the server whilst disabling internet connection so that this computer can connect to the server but not the internet. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by changing the IP settings from "obtain an IP address automatically" to "use the following IP address" and giving it the actual IP address of my machine, then leaving the default gateway and preferred DNS server empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to simply do `route -f` in cmd after you've connected to the network. This will prevent internet traffic from being sent to your router. This might be a little simpler than what youre doing - it essentially does the same thing, but all in one convienent little command.